# Remove strings at column based of another column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where in the NEXT_OP_NO column I can only have the numbers that are on the OP_NO column.

So I have to remove the value '130' in the selected line.

How can that be done? Its something that can appear anywhere on the string, beginning, middle, or end and whatever I try does not give the expected outcome.

Tried charindex and others with no success.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Sample data and expected results are a must for SQL questions

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use case expression ?
smth like:
case
when NEXT_OP_NO = OP_NO then ..